# Find the surface satisfying $r+s=0$, touching $z=4x^2+y^2$ along its section by the plane $y=2x+1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$r+s = 0\implies (D^2+DD')z = 0\implies z = \phi_1(y) + \phi_2(y-x)$

This is the surface. Since it touches $z=4x^2+y^2$, the values of $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ of both are equal.

Equating $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ of both surfaces, we get
$\quad\phi_2(y-x) = -8x + C1$

Equating $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ of both surfaces, we get
$\quad \phi_1(y) = 8xy+y^2 + C2$

$\implies z = 8xy+y^2-8x +C1+C2$

Now I am not able to find $C1+C2$. The answer given in the text book is $z = 8xy + y^2 - 8x + 4y - 2$

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: What is the meaning of $r$ and $s$ ?

Comment: $r=\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}$, $s=\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x \partial y}$ and $D=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ , $D'=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}$

Comment: Thank you. I had forgotten these notations.